# AJAX success request "message text" to be displayed back

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a web page that calls AJAX request that sends the data to the database and updates it. I need to display the message back to the user on the webpage that the data has been updated, however currently, nothing is being displayed. Moreover, no error message is being generated.
My HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="input-group" id = "contentID">  
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="showname" value="Show Fields" id = "showName" style="margin-right: 5px;"/>
            </div>
```

My ajax request looks like below:

```
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {'postData':JSON.stringify(postData)},
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Data was succesfully updated';
            $("#contentID").text(successmessage); #Is this correct?

        },
        error: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Error';
            $("#contentID").text(successmessage);
        },


});
```

Comment: Error condition is not proper, it should be  $("#contentID").html(successmessage);

Comment: You've forgotten your `#` try with $("#contentID").html(successmessage);

Comment: why downvoted this question?

Comment: now you added the missing `#` without marking it as an edit.

Comment: @user4943236 I'm asking myself the same.

Comment: @user4943236 Is it working or are you still having an issue? It would be helpful if you could provide some more details

Comment: Try to display your text in an other div. Just create one and lookwhat happens and tell us please

Comment: @Manikiran this worked

Comment: @Erlaunis: .html (successmessage) worked, the text one wasn't worked, and thanks, I created a new Div to display my message.

Comment: @user4943236 So, your problem is resolved ?

Comment: @Erlaunis: yes, thank you it resolved, but it opened another problem. gonna post a new question soon

Comment: @user4943236 I think that adding a new div is the best option because, if your `.html()` worked with the id `contentID`, it will remove all your content to be replace by your text. So, your button will be removed.

Comment: @Erlaunis: yeah, I agree. created a new div to avoid removing my button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ajax code has an error:

Please Change:

```
$("contentID").text(successmessage);
```

To

```
$("#contentID").html(successmessage);
```

Comment: you should have posted it as a comment to the question: this is not an answer

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Oh really? So whats the answer then?

Comment: This is a fix to the issue so it's a solution. Just as good as giving an answer. This should not be down voted. If the OP accepts it as a comment then the question should be removed, this gives the OP chance to mark the question as answered to help others who make the same mistake.

Comment: @Manikiran: tried this, it is not working. Nothing is being displayed on the webpage. I need to show a message to user if the content is updated or not.

Comment: yeah, really. $('#contentID').text('SOME TEXT'); works just fine, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpvpp2sh/  obviously, the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: @NewToJS this is an unmotivated "correction" to a line of code that in fact is working fine already. even if it were useful (which is not) it should have been posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Maybe a more detailed answer would be appreciated? Explanation of the different selectors? I have seen many people post short answers like this so I don't see the problem but I do believe it should have more detail to explain different selectors.

Comment: You've fallen victim to another "stealth" edit. Remember that last question you answered? ;-) same thing here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Screw it man, lost interest in this helping business. Anyways thanks for your advice's :)

Comment: before OP's edit: `$("#contentID").text(successmessage); #Is this correct?`  after the edit: `$("#contentID").text(successmessage); #Is this correct?`

Comment: I know the feeling man; I've fallen to those stealth edits countless times.

Comment: ROFL after all this fights, the OP agrees my code works :P

Comment: @Manikiran: .html(Successmessage) worked. thanks. # was a typo and it was being missed as I did some last minute efforts to make my code worked. If you edit the answer, I'll mark it as official one

Comment: @Manikiran: your commented thing worked.. and don't know why you guys fought. Its not that fixing the typo worked. I had to change code

Comment: @user4943236 Updated :-)